# Prevent all files of a directory from being uploaded to svn repository

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I have just installed AnkhSVN plugin in Visual Studio 2012 and have created a free repository on assembla.

I'd add a project to my subversion repository successfully.
But I want a few directories not to upload to repository like my `Elmah` log (that is in `xml`) and directories where I store data.

I tried adding a subversion property (right click -> subversion -> subversion properties then add) with following details

```
Property Name: svn:ignore  
Pattern: *
```

But all new files or changed files inside these folders are being updated to repository on committing.

Please help me how can prevent all files of a directory from being uploaded to svn repository completely..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are already under version control, adding a `svn:ignore` on it will not help. See this [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit) about the subject.

If you wanted to ignore all files in a directory, in the parent directory add a `svn:ignore` for the name of the child directory. If it is for a specific file, or pattern, add the `svn:ignore` for that file by name, or use globs (like `*.log` for all `.log` files).

For the ones that are now under version control you want to remove from being committed, you will need to remove them from Subversion, and then add the `svn:ignore` property.

Comment: Can u please describe in more details..? suppose I have `abc` directory in root of the project and I don't want to add any new file created or modified in this directory to be uploaded to repository from now..?? I am using AnkhSVN

Comment: In the rood directory add `svn:ignore` with the content of `abc`, and don't check in the `abc` folder. If it is already in svn, delete it. svnbook.org is your friend.

Comment: Once you do this, you can also right click->subversion->ignore->* on not added files.